# How to write unit test case for open popup using Jasmine?

Tags: angular, jasmine

Hi I am writing unit test cases for my application in jasmine. I have one bootstrap popup. On clicking of button I am trying to open the popup. I have written following code to open popup.

```
it('onPopupOpen', async(() => {
    let button = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('#adduser');
    button.click();
    expect(document.getElementById("#adduser").innerHTML).toContain('modal-dialog');
}));
```

Below is my anchor tag.

```
 <a href="javascript:;" (click)="addUser()" id="adduser">
                    <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> {{'users.management.NewUser' | translate}}
   </a>
```

Below is my popup.

```
<div class="modal fade" bsModal #editorModal="bs-modal" tabindex="-1">
        <div class="modal-dialog" id="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    //textbox and other cotrols
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to make below line of code work but this is not working

```
 expect(document.getElementById("#adduser").innerHTML).toContain('modal-dialog');
```

Can someone help me to make above code works? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.